# Adding scroll bars with Java Swing into a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I've seen several posts about this subject but I cannot solve the problem with the information provided there. I'm trying to add scroll bars (vertical and horizontal) with the following code into a `JTextArea` as follows:

```
public FPrincipale() {

        JFrame wframe = new JFrame();

        JPanel wpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel tpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        textzone = new JTextArea(" ",20, 50);
        textzone.setLineWrap(true);
        textzone.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        //Here I try to add the scroll bar
        JScrollPane wscroll = new JScrollPane(textzone, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        wscroll.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        wscroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        wframe.add(wscroll);
        wframe.setVisible(true);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Close");      

        bpanel.add(b1);
        bpanel.add(b2);     
        bpanel.add(b3);     
        bpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        tpanel.add(textzone);
        tpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        tpanel.add(wscroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        wpanel.add(bpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        wpanel.add(tpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        wframe.setLocation(150, 100);
        wframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

        b1.addActionListener(new b1Listener());
        b2.addActionListener(new b2Listener());
        b3.addActionListener(new b3Listener());

        this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));     

        wframe.add(wpanel);
        wframe.setVisible(true);
        wframe.setSize(640, 640);
        wframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wframe.setTitle("Main Window");
        pack();

    }
```

Nevertheless, when the window is created the scroll bar doesn't work even if I reduce the window's size:

**Normal Window:**

[image]

**Reduced size:**

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting rid of the class to `setPreferredSize`, this are going to mess you up. Later in your code you're calling `tpanel.add(textzone);`, which is removing the `JTextArea` from the `JScrollPane` and adding it to `tpanel` (you then add the `JScrollPane` to it was well, which is why you have that little square next to it).

Start by applying a `BorderLayout` to `tpanel`

```
JPanel tpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Remove the line where you add the scroll pane to the frame...

```
//wFrame.add(wscroll);
```

Then add only the `JScrollPane` to `tpanel`

```
//tpanel.add(textzone);
tpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
tpanel.add(wscroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```